# Stack Exchange global inbox link pointed to incorrect question

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, global-inbox

I have my Stack Overflow account associated with my Server Fault account. Recently, I posted a question on Server Fault. After two days, I visited the Stack Overflow home page and found that the top left corner was displaying a red-colored alert by Stack Exchange for "1 new message" received for my Server Fault question. So I clicked that message to see the reply I got. But, this opened some other non-relevant question on Server Fault which I had not asked. Is this a bug or I did something wrong? Shouldn't it take me to the page with my question?

The inbox of my Stack Exchange tooltip window has the following message:

> answer on How to create web site (from file) using IIS7?

which ideally should navigate to this URL:

https://serverfault.com/questions/186575/how-to-create-web-site-from-file-using-iis7

But when I clicked on the inbox message, it navigated to this URL:

https://serverfault.com/questions/186488/is-this-a-good-plugin-based-software-marketing-scheme/186575

I did this twice.

Note:
Surprisingly, I was looking at the same thing from here on MSO just now while writing this message, and the links are now correct! Please believe me. I could tell you above info because I had saved those pages in favorite links. Don't know what went wrong earlier. Might be that when your message appears in the inbox (for this question), the previous message is corrected automatically?

Comment: @Jeff: I found more exact scenario..
- The StackExchange inbox message on "StackOverflow page" has incorrect link
- BUT the same message when seen on StackExchange inbox in "metaStackOverflow page" has a correct link.

Comment: I thought I was just crazy, it happened to me this morning for Gaming Stack Exchange.

Comment: This happened to me several times and now again.

Comment: I can see that this question is selected as favorite by somebody. Thanks to all.. But I don't see any indication of the same on my profile page. Like "This question has been favorited by X users".. Is this because of the migration going on for this meta (top note)?

Comment: @Anil, there is no notification for a question being favorited, unless it's a new feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>This has been fixed in the repo, and will go out sometime tonight eventually.</del>  *Has been deployed.*

As [Michael](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145982/michael-mrozek) surmised, the problem was using the current site to build the links displayed in the inbox.  Accordingly, this was just a display bug, once the fix is out everything should be hunky-dory (ie. no data loss).

Comment: It's still there - I guess it hasn't been deployed yet

Comment: @Pekka - correct.  Some excitement yesterday threw our build schedule off.

Answer (score 5):

I just got this too. If it helps with debugging, the problem appears to be that when answer links are posted, the corresponding question ID is looked up from the current site, not the site that the answer was posted on. So if site A has question ID `n` with answer ID `m`, and you get an alert about new answer `m` and check your inbox on site B, it will lookup answer ID `m` on site **B**, not A. If answer `m` on B is posted on question `k`, you'll get a URL for site A but for question ID `k` instead of `n`:

- Currently: http://A.stackexchange.com/questions/k/question-title/m#m
- Should be: http://A.stackexchange.com/questions/n/question-title/m#m

Comment: +1 for doing your homework

Comment: I can confirm this behavior (and have a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/oInY9.png) to boot). Interestingly, this will only cause an issue if the target Post Id on the target site happens to be an answer on the site you're currently on; if it matches a question or doesn't match anything then the URL will resolve more accurately.

Comment: Sounds very much logical! +1

Answer (score 0):

It's happening to me too; twice now.  I had [an answer on one of my questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8390/xbox-360-surround-sound-gaming-headsets/8460#8460) in my inbox, but when I clicked on it, it redirected me to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/how-to-start-guide-for-ruse/2586#2586) in another question.

I've [included a screenshot](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/Ya-U1toEtX_iY_4GuYonkA?feat=directlink) that shows that the hover is pointing to another question even though the inbox isn't showing that question/answer.